# Google Sheet Scripts and "IMPORTDATA" stoped working after years of working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 6 copies of the same spreadsheet that is used for a running race management. Each sheet may be used for different races that occur on the same weekend but in different locations.
These have worked fine for years. They have various scripts that do things like clear a section of cells, move data from sheet to sheet, etc, pretty basic stuff. Other sheets access these sheets using IMPORTDATA, but only a single cell.
Several of the sheets had scripts stop working, and any sheet trying to access a cell from that sheet using IMPORTDATA also does not work giving a #ref error.
Making a copy of a non-functioning sheet will work for a day or two before scripts and Importdata stop working again.

I am wondering if I am reaching some Google limit, the only errors i receive in Summary of Failures email are nothing unusual , "service timed out" of course because script is not working.

Comment: It does sound like you're hitting a usage limit.  Have you looked at the Google console?

Comment: I created/wrote these quite a while ago. Excuse my old brain ignorance, but how do I find the console ?

Comment: In the G Suite Developers Hub It shows the current "broken" sheet as 90% error rate starting at the time it stopped working. The other identical sheets have zero error rates, although those also have stopped working in the past. Duplicating any non-functioning sheet cures it for days to weeks before stopping.

Comment: The issue started about 6 weeks ago. Were there any changes in Google policy that may have caused this?

Comment: I do not know how to view any usage totals that would lead me to confirm my suspicion of Usage Limit.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's been a policy change to Sheets (I haven't used them too much lately), but I've seen similar behavior with the other APIs.  If you go into developer.google.com, scroll to the bottom and find Google API Console that may help.

Comment: Looking at the API console it says "You don’t have any APIs available to use yet".